# Facebook IDP in wso2 IS social.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator

Tags: facebook, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure Facebook as ID provider in WSO2 IS.. every blogs looks so simple in reading and configuring but unfortunately I am getting below error every time. not sure whats wrong in this

Can anyone please help me out?

logs:

```
    rbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2017-11-18 23:34:52,692+1300]
[2017-11-18 23:36:59,282] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator} -  Failed to process Facebook Connect response.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.ApplicationAuthenticatorException: Received access token is invalid.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.getToken(FacebookAuthenticator.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(FacebookAuthenticator.java:204)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:432)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:406)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:117)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:171)
```

I am able to reach to the facebook login page and this error is coming after facebook athentication

Comment: What is the Identity Server version and Facebook connector version that you are using ?

Comment: HI Jayanga,  Thanks for coming on this. I am using IS 5.0.1, but not using any connector and also not sure what is this for.. I have just created an APP in facebook and and trying to connect it via WSO2 IS. Please Let me know if I am missing anything